# Get a Text data type in stored procedure

Tags: informix

I need to have a Text data type column (instead of an Lvarchar, for space reasons) in a table. But I have a problem. If I pass the insert/select statement from C#, with the parameter being a string, the connector will do the type conversion automatically and everything works fine.
But I want to have it on a stored procedure. Although, it doesn't let me:

- have a Text data type as an input parameter;
- have load/unload statements in a stored procedure (that way I could just pass the string and unload and then load it to the table);
- can't seem to make a data type conversion in informix...

So... Given this situation, how can I possibly do this? I'm aware that a Text data type is hell to work with but it's also great for saving storage space and not pre-setting a size limit. Correct me if I'm mistaken, as I'm new to Informix.
In this case, I just need to save text (which may or may not be big/small) and return it when needed. Don't need to work it in any way other than that.

Comment: You can't use LOAD or UNLOAD in a stored procedure; they're not built-in SQL commands (statements), but are simulated in client software such as DB-Access or DB-Load.

Comment: To use a BYTE or TEXT blob in a stored procedure, you have to use the keyword REFERENCES.   This compiles: `create procedure insert_text(t references text)
    insert into blob_table values(t);
end procedure;` (you can create a table: `create table blob_table(t text in table);` too, before or after creating the stored procedure).  However, then using that stored procedure is tricky; you can't use it from DB-Access.  You'd have to use a program — I know how to do it in ESQL/C, but I'm not sure about either JDBC or ODBC.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks. I searched and ended up with this: create function insert_text(t references text) 
returning references text;

 define te references text;

 insert into blob_table values(t); 

 FOREACH cursor1 FOR
        SELECT t INTO te FROM blob_table
        RETURN te WITH RESUME;
    END FOREACH;

end function;
Although, it does insert (it's through the informix SDK for .NET) it doesn't return anything... So, it really doesn't fit my purposes. I need it to do both things. If it inserts but doesn't return I can't have it.

Comment: It'd be nice if it'd work (and it should, judging by the examples even seen) . But if it doesn't I'll probably sitck with lvarchar...